# Binary Search in C - Pointers and Memory

Tags: algorithm, c

I got a warning when I am returning "list" in the function createList "Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'list' returned"

I am confused about pointers and memory allocation and not sure how to fix it.

```
int* createList(int quantity) {
    int list[quantity];

    printf("Please enter a list of numbers\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < quantity ; i++){
        scanf("%i",&list[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

int findNumber(int number) {
    printf("Please chose a number\n");
    scanf("%i",&number);
    return number;
}

int main() {
    int quantity;
    printf("How many numbers do you want?\n");
    scanf("%i",&quantity);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this function you declare an array of `int`:

```
int* createList(int quantity) {
    int list[quantity];    /* <- here */

    printf("Please enter a list of numbers\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &list[i]);
    }
    return list;
} /* list is free'd here, so you return a pointer to free'd memory */
```

Accessing the free'd memory you return may cause your program to crash or give you access to part of the memory previously owned by your `int` array that's since been allocated by other entities in your program. It may vary from day to day what the effect will be. It may even look like it works sometimes. You need to find other means to pass your arrays around. I have ideas but since this is far from working code, you could try to get help at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.

> How to Ask @ Code Review
>
> Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and
>   the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question.

Comment: I would write a comment and flag the question in the future. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @dfhwze I tried, but I don't have reputation to write comments :-)

Comment: Oh yes, been there to :p This can be a bit frustating at the beginning.

Comment: @dfhwze et al.  Please refer to: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/

Comment: @StephenRauch Ted Lyngmo fixed a formatting mistake by the OP. Is there a reason why I should not have approved it?

Comment: Yes, it should not be approved. As the meta questions states, we should not "fix" the code in the question.

Comment: @StephenRauch There was no code fix, only formatting and a correction in the usage of MarkDown. The accepted answer in the link you provided allows such changes.

Comment: @dfhwze,I suggest you look more carefully at the suggested edits that you approved: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/117513 & https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/117515.  In both cases more experienced reviewers rejected the edits.  Fixing because of MarkDown problems means the OP did not understand how to do Markdown, (IE: usually the entire block needs to be indented) but that is not the case here.

Comment: @StephenRauch Missing a markdown when otherwise doing well has never been the end for me. I fixed it because it was a so obvious typo.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I understand your confusion.  I was also there previously.  But you reformatted the OP's code.  In a Code Review situation, this is not what we do.  We comment on the code as presented.

Comment: @StephenRauch Fair enough ... My first try. I'm looking forward to what I'm working at getting love :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, this is why your answer, even though it probably should not not have been applied to this question (the code does not work) was upvoted.  We want to encourage as many as we can to come and take the time discuss questions here.  My only quibble was with the edit, not with the answer...  Cheers.

Comment: @StephenRauch - Ah .. Ok, I'm from `SO` and quick-fix as soon as I see someone making a simple typo-like mistake.  Well, cheers mate!  Off to the brew again! - and the reason I've started frequenting _review_ is ... my upcoming review - and I'm nervous about it.

Comment: @StephenRauch Alright, I'll be more strict in approving suggested code formatting edits. Nuff said :)